# Android : How to show custom dialog from thread

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog, android-asynctask, ui-thread

I stack with this, I'm trying to create application using TabLayout. I have 3 tabs (3 different activities). I also got service which reads my gps position - that works fine. I got thread which post to the web server user position - that works to.

Now I'm trying to create thread which ask web server if there are any messages for user. If there are - thread try to show custom dialog (2 text views and gallery - it works if i start action from activity by clicking button), and there problem starts I know i can't update UI form threads different from main thread but i don't know how to work around this. I tried to use AsyncTask - failed - i don't want to assign AsyncTask to specific Activity as inner private class.

I wish  I could show my custom dialog regardless of the tab on which user is currently using.

Thread works fine, but how to show that dialog.

I read about runOnUIThread but don't know how to use it.

Any ideas, any similar examples ??

Comment: Next question. What happens if I start thread in one Activity "A" and change Tab and other activity "B" will by on top, and handler from Activity "A "receive msg to update UI .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `runOnUiThread` is easy.

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        YourActivity.this.showDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: No enclosing instance of the type MyActivity is accessible in scope

Comment: Oh this code should have been posted in an inner thread class of your activity class. If you can get a reference to your activity, just give it to the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Handler. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: So i need to use Handler in my Thread, and in every Activity ?

Comment: No, use AsyncTasks to notify a handler defined in each Activity. http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: If i create Handler in every Activity, my Handler from working Thread would know tho whom send msg to update UI.